# How to check stored procedure return value elegantly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Here is my current implementation of a stored procedure which returns Order status for a given Order ID. There are two situations,

1. there is matched Order ID and I will retrieve the related status,
2. there is no matched Order ID (i.e. non-existing Order ID).

My confusion is, how to implement the two functions elegantly/efficiently in one stored procedure, so that I return matched Order ID for situation 1 and also indicate client no matched Order ID in situation 2?

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + ADO.Net + .Net 3.5 as client, and using SQL Server 2008 as server.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStatus] 
    @ID [nvarchar](256),
    @Status [int] output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    -- Insert statements for procedure here 
    SELECT @Status = [Status] 
    FROM [dbo].[OrderStatus]        
    WHERE (@ID = [ID]);
END
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3):

why are you using output parameter.

you just need to take your stored procedure result in dataset of the data access layer.
just check that **if (dataset != null)** then take value else return appropriate message to your business layer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple approaches you can take:

1. Keep everything as is and in your .NET code, if the @status value returned is DBNull, then it will indicate situation 2, otherwise situation 1.
2. Add a RETURN statement to the SPROC and use

   Dim returnValue As New SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int)

   returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

   Cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue)

   in your .NET code to explicitly identify what the SPROC returned and take action   accordingly.

As an additional tip, use a SET instead of SELECT when assigning the value to @Status variable in the SPROC. This will guarantee that you get a NULL back if there is no match found. So,

`
    -- Insert statements for procedure here

```
SET @Status = SELECT [Status] 
FROM [dbo].[OrderStatus]            
WHERE (@ID = [ID]);`
```

Comment: Thanks, for your solution 1, should I call ExecuteNonQuery or call ExecuteReader?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "if statements" inside the stored procedures. the web site at bottom gives you some tips.

http://translate.google.com.br/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.firebase.com.br%2Fpipermail%2Flista_firebase.com.br%2F2005-November%2F021883.html&sl=pt&tl=en&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8